# TestNG An internal error occurred during launching

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

I created a TestNG class (FirstTest.java) and when I run the test case as TestNG Test, I am getting the following error.

**An internal error occurred during: "Launching FirstTest".
java.lang.NullPointerException**

Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

If anyone knows Please Help!

Comment: Could you provide the full stacktrace and your test class?

Answer (score 11):

I encountered a problem with similar symptoms today. I'm not sure if it is the same problem but it matches everything in your question.

In my case, the log files said:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2015-12-03 15:49:19.369
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Launching NewTest".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.testng.eclipse.maven.MavenTestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider.getVMArgsFromPom(MavenTestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider.java:74)
```

So my problem was that the TestNG-plugin in Eclipse failed to find the pom-file, as I don't use Maven. Anyway, after uninstalling the optional M2E (Maven...) part of the TestNG Eclipse plugin I could run my TestNG test cases successfully.

If you have the same issue, you uninstall the M2E part in Eclipse by selecting

- Help
- Install new software...
- What is already installed?
- Select the TestNG M2E software and click uninstall

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 8):

Need to uninstall M2E. 
I uninstalled like below path:
Help->Install new software->Already installed -> Uninstall M2E

Answer (score 3):

I Installed TestNG in Eclipse and tried to execute test case but got error message "Launching Test Case has encountered a problem, an Internal error occur during during launching Test Case "

i guess TestNG-plugin in Eclipse might failed,i uninstalled optional M2E (Maven...). After uninstalling the optional M2E (Maven...) part of the TestNG Eclipse plugin I could run my TestNG test cases successfully.

If you have the same issue, you uninstall the M2E part in Eclipse by selecting

Help
Install new software...
What is already installed?
Select the TestNG M2E software and click uninstall

Comment: Thanks Rahul, your answer is helped me to resolved my issue. :)

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting the same issue, I just uninstalled TestNG M2E software.

Steps:

1. Help
2. Install new software.
3. Install/Update.
4. Click on Install/Update link (right-hand side)
5. Select TestNG M2E from the list.
6. Uninstall.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I faced the same problem. The eclipse failed to initiate the action,

To solve this problem, follow the below steps

1. Go To Help
2. Choose Install New Software
3. Choose Whats been installed?
4. Uninstall the TestNG M2e from the list
5. Restart the application

Answer (score 1):

[The issue](https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/pull/207) was fixed, please use the latest release 6.12.0.201709050550: `http://beust.com/eclipse`.

Link the similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46046386/4867232)