# TestNG does not run, shows java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

I am using Eclipse Luna and i have written this basic code.

```
package TestNg;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class NewTest {
    WebDriver driver;
  @Test
  public void f() {
      driver =new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("http://www.spicejet.com/");
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
  }
}
```

But when i try to run the test as "Run as TestNG test"
i get the below error.

[Please find the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unnX3.jpg)

Comment: try renaming `f()` to `testF()`

Comment: i have tried with different names too , doesn't work

Comment: check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34070227/5146424) helps!

Comment: Thanks , it worked!!