# Error running TestNG on Eclipse: Launching SampleTest has encountered a p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m

Tags: eclipse, testng

I am getting error when trying to run TestNG on Eclipse, my script is very simple as screenshot attached. I'm using TestNG version org.testng.eclipse_6.9.10.201512020421\lib\testng.jar

[image: Error running TestNG on Eclipse]

Comment: Check if [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34070227/5146424) helps.!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TestNG An internal error occurred during launching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050615/testng-an-internal-error-occurred-during-launching)

Answer (score 1):

i was facing same problem.................

solve:

Uninstall the M2E(Maven) from your eclipse IDE. This has worked for me. Check the following steps:

Help-->Install new software-->What is already installed?-->Select the TestNG M2E software and click uninstall