# java.lang.NullPointerException error with eclipse and testng

Tags: java, eclipse, testng-eclipse

am not able to run my first program using testNG and eclipse due following error logs.I am using eclipse and testNG for the first time.Thank you.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at 
    org.testng.eclipse.maven.MavenTestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider
   .getVMArgsFromPom(MavenTestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider.java:74)
    at         
    org.testng.eclipse.maven.MavenTestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider.
    getVmArguments(MavenTestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider.java:39)
    at   
    org.testng.eclipse.ui.util.ConfigurationHelper.
    getJvmArgs(ConfigurationHelper.java:166)
    at 
    org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.
    getVMArguments(TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:364)
    at
    org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.
    launchTypes(TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:158)
    at 
    org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.
    launch(TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:90)
    at
    org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.
    launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at 
    org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.
    launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at 
    org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.
    buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at 
    org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at 
    org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

    **Session data**
    eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
    java.version=1.8.0_65
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
    Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64
```

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml please?

Comment: This worked for me... [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34070227/5648912)