# When iam trying to install TestNG in to Eclipse Version: Mars.1 getting error as software contains unsinged content

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I tried to install **testng** software in **eclipse mars** but I am getting below error

> Warning: You are installing software that contains unsigned content. The Authenticity or validity of this software cannot be Established . Do you wish to continue with the installation ?

After completing the installtion I wrote a sample test case and I got below error message and I cannot run any testng anotations testcases

> Java.lang.nullpointerexception .

Comment: See if [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050615/testng-an-internal-error-occurred-during-launching/34070227#34070227) helps you.

Comment: Can you share code you have written? Do you getting option to create TESTNG class in eclipse?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please make sure that you don't rush questions and make them of as high standard as you can. Head to the help page and read the how to ask a good question section. Once again, welcome!

Comment: Please add the complete Exception. Installing unsigned content is most  likely unrelated to your error. Without your code and/or a stacktrace we can't do much to help you.

Answer (score 0):

i had problems with testNG and mars . 
try to reinstall mars and testNG with the latest version of testNG
this is the mars version i work with :

Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)