# An internal error occurred during launching testng in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, testng, testng-eclipse

I have created the simple test class and getting error while executing it "An internal error occurred during: "Launching test". java.lang.NullPointerException".

I am fed up with this problem. I searched a lot on google and applied all the possible solutions but still getting same problem. I know, it is configuration problem but not able to figure out where?

**Followed Steps to create the project:**

- Open Eclipse
- Install TestNG Plugin
- Create Java Project
- Add TestNG Library
- Create TestNG Class
- Execute that class (as above)

**Applied solution :**

- Reinstalled the Eclipse.
- Reinstalled the TestNG Plugin
- Uninstalled the MVC TestNG plugin

Source Code:

```
package usermigration;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class test {


@Test   
public void a()
{
    System.out.println("a");
}

}
```

Comment: share the complete stacktrace for the exception please

Comment: It is not generating any stacktrace. I am getting popup while executing the file.

Comment: did you setup the `testng.xml` file?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have identified the root cause. I have removed the M2E jars from eclipse and it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

looks like it's a regression introduced by PR [#351](https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/pull/351/files), it should now be fixed in the beta channel: `http://beust.com/eclipse-beta`, will deploy a hotfix soon.

---

-- Edit

now the hotfix 6.12.0.201709050550 is released: `https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/6.12.0/`