# Run as TestNG is getting error "An internal error occurred during: "Launching testfile"

Tags: eclipse, selenium, automation, automated-tests, testng

I am new to the `TestNG` framework. I have installed `TestNG` and I have `TestNG` jar in my C drive,  and I have added `TestNG` dependency in `POM.xml` also.

```
<dependency>

<groupId>org.testng</groupId>

<artifactId>testng</artifactId>

<version>6.14.3</version>

<scope>test</scope>

</dependency>
```

When I am doing Run as TestNG it is showing below error

> "An internal error occurred during: "Launching testfile".
>   org/testng/eclipse/launch/ITestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider.getClasspath(Lorg/eclipse/debug/core/ILaunchConfiguration;)Ljava/util/List;"

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Mohamed

I have tried to uninstall TestNG M2E Integration(Optional) in Eclipse .  But  uninstall button is disabled. I could see only update button is enabled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050615/testng-an-internal-error-occurred-during-launching. Try this

Comment: Hi Akbar, I have tried that already. I am not able to uninstall TestNG M2E Integration(Optional) in Eclipse . Uninstall button is disabled. Could you please help to resolve ?